# How to Access a Sql lite Variable From one Js to another Js in Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sqlite, cordova

Hi I have implemented a SqlLite in my project and i am creating the DB in Login.js, But My problem is Now i need to update a columns from Another JS.
How to access a DB variable from another JS.
Code A.js:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        window.db = window.openDatabase("SP_DB", "1.0", "SPDB", 200000);
    };
```

Now i need to Access that **window.db** from another JS for columns add or update. How to achieve this

Code B.js:
Here I need to access that **window.db** variable, i don't want to create DB again.

```
var saveimg = document.getElementById("saveimg");
    saveimg.addEventListener('click', goInsert, false);


    function goInsert() {

       window.db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    function insertDB(tx) {

      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SP(FirstName,LastName,Address) VALUES ("' + document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value + '","'
            + document.getElementById("txtLastName").value + '","' + document.getElementById("txtAddress").value + '")');

    }


    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
    }


    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }


    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SP', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }
```

Comment: Store it in session or make it global

Comment: Ya i have stored it in Session, while storing it is object but while getting it is in string format and that to empty. It is throwing undefined

Comment: share your code so that we can see what exactly is happening

Comment: Please find the updated code

Comment: Have you tried using [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin? You should be able to use it like `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase` on any page including a reference to `cordova.js` after `deviceReady` event fired.

Comment: Yes i have used, but my problem is i need to update a DB from different java script.

Comment: I don't see a reason why Cordova-sqlite-storage should not work on another page in case you include a link to cordova.js on it.

Comment: I have already included

Answer (score 2):

Your variable window.db is in the global scope.  So you can access it anywhere within the same page where it is defined.
I hope the 'Another JS' that you are mentioning is in the same page. If it is in a different page it will not work.

Cordova applications should adopt the SPA (Single Page Application) design. If you do not use a SPA you need to define the required variables in each page. Please check https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#1-spa-is-your-friend

Comment: Another.JS is a diffrent JS and why it is not possible